# How to add the `checkbox` in the `ngFor` loop

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular5

In my `ngFor` loop, I am adding multiple checkboxes, all are added. But Behaves like `radio` button. I can able to select only one checkbox at a time. what is wrong here? any one help me?

here is my template:

```
<div class="vas-obs vas-selected" *ngFor="let vas of vasDatas;let i=index;">
          <div class="vas-obs-text checkbox-container">{{appProps[vas.title]}}
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="vas{{i}}">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="vas-obs-value"><sup class="currency">THB</sup>{{vas.value}}</div>
            <div class="horizantal-line-obs"></div>
            <div class="vas-obs-text-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adip</div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You actually have a different name for every checkbox...like vas1, vas2, etc...you need to have something like `vas[]` as a name, and all of your checkbox named tha same...so, something like `name="vas[]" value="{{i}}">` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="vas{{i}}">
```

The checked attribute is shared between all inputs. This field would need to be dynamic, just like your name attribute.

You could add a field to each vas object upon creation

```
checked: boolean
```

Then, model bind to the checked field in each 'vas' object

Here's a stackblitz showing that idea: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-km8sew

Which is basically just this, just substitute your object fields, etc...:

```
<div class="vas-obs vas-selected" *ngFor="let vas of vasDatas; let i=index;">
  <div class="vas-obs-text checkbox-container">
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="vas.checked" name="vas{{i}}"> {{vas.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not able to get you, can you help me by updating my code?

Comment: Edited my answer @3gwebtrain

Comment: so, I have to build the checked values on object right?

Comment: Correct, you would need some way to bind a value to the actual object

Comment: I use this, still not luck I am not getting function trigger on change as well `<input type="checkbox" [checked]="vas.checked" value="vas.value" name="vas[{{i}}]" (change)="updateChecked(vas, $event)" >`